# invalid identifier with sub query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i want to access st.Gr_number column in Subquery
but it gives me error

> ORA-00904: "ST"."GR_NUMBER": invalid identifier

```
    Select st.Gr_number,
st.STUDENT_ID, st.course, 
st.Student_Name,cr.course_name,
st.Status as Active,
st.GR_NUMBER as Fee_Detail,
(Select sum(nvl(r.amt, 0)-nvl(f.fee_amount, 0)) as Current_Balance
from FEE_SCHEDULE f 
full outer join (select gr_number, to_char(pmt_date,'yyyymm') pmt_month, sum(nvl(pmt_amount,0)) amt 
                 from FEE_PAYMENT_POSTED
                 Where pmt_type = 'FEE'
                 and   gr_number = st.Gr_number
                 group by gr_number, to_char(pmt_date,'yyyymm')
                ) r 
             on f.GR_NUMBER=r.GR_NUMBER and f.SCHEDULE_MONTH=r.pmt_month

where nvl(f.gr_number,r.gr_number) = st.Gr_number
) currentBalance

from student st inner join course cr on cr.course_id=st.course
where st.student_id=:P166_STUDENT_ID and upper(st.Status)='STUDYING';
```

Answer (score 0):

In you inner query you are trying to use `st.GR_NUMBER` while it still hasn't been defined which it does in the outer query.

This is the place `gr_number = st.Gr_number` where the issue is.

Comment: error on line number 12 and 16 which means inner query not getting value of st.GR_NUMBER i.e define in main query

Answer (score 0):

This line is causing an error:

```
            and   gr_number = st.Gr_number
```

Although quite hard to tell from your formatting, this is nested two levels deep:

```
select . . . ,
       (select . . .
        from . . . 
             (select . . .
              from . . . gr . . .
              where . . . and
                    gr_number = st.Gr_number
             ) level3
       ) level2
from . . . st . . .
```

Oracle's scoping rules only allow table references to be recognized one level deep.  So, within `level3` you can reference `level2`, but not the outer level.

You have a very complicated query.  There is no way to know if this is the only problem, so I am not going to even attempt fixing it.

I would suggest that you ask another question with a simplified query.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have redefined my query upto level 2 and updated my code but error remain same .Please have a look